# Adding action links when posting Facebook Photos

Tags: facebook-graph-api

It's easy to include action links to items posted to the feed using Facebook's Graph API using the "actions" object, which appear along side "Comment" and "Like" below the feed post. Like:

```
"actions": [{"name":"Vote!","link":"http://voting.com/123/vote"}]
```

But, is it possible to include the same action links when posting Photos so the link will show up next to Comment and Like below a photo? I've tried the obvious (i.e. including the `actions` object on a photo post, which doesn't work) but wondering if anyone's found a workaround for this.

Comment: I never knew action links were possible.  Thank you for showing me something I did not know.  However, I don't know the answer to your question.  It may help to know how you post a link.  Also is this something you can reproduce in the Graph API Explorer?

Comment: Sure, you can add actions when posting a Post object by including the array listed in the question as the "actions" attribute, like described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ And it works fine in the Graph API explorer - check it out!

Comment: So are you saying the Graph AP explorer will or wont let you post action links to a photo?

Comment: An error is returned when adding action links to a photo, and action links added to an album are accepted but seem to be ignored.

Comment: Ok, sounds like you have a good candidate for a bug.  Log it at: developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Having the same issue. I posted to https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/174416759390604. Since this issue has been around for so long I'm guessing it's not a bug afterall?

Answer (score 0):

You can only add Action Links to things published on the user's timeline / wall. You cannot add action links to Photos, Notes, Events, etc.

If you post a photo to the user's wall (using `FB.ui`), you can add an action link to it, but if the user views the photo from the `Wall Photos` album, the Action Link will be hidden.

If you see the screenshots in the documentation, you will see that all instances of Action Links are on the Timeline / Wall.